Webserver port 80 and server side NAT port translation query
From my home computer (192.168.0.2) which sits behind a domestic router and the router is of course using NAT, I want to connect to google.com (ping returns 216.58.204.78). 192.168.0.2 opens a local TCP port e.g. 60000 and a message is sent to 216.58.204.78:80 via my router NAT which translates e.g. to :60010. I understand that replies to 192.168.0.2:60000 will actually be to :60010 and my router will use the NAT table to forward the reply to 192.168.0.2.
My questions are around what happens when that message arrives at the Google side. Does the Google router just send the message to the google server using port 80, and if so, what happens when the Google server replies? Does the server reply on a different port, which is then translated on the way out, and therefore further replies from my machine are no longer to port 80 and are to whatever the 'public facing' port is? I'm a bit lost in what happens on the Google side with regards to NATing.

I'm not sure where you are coming up with the stuff about :60010. outbound NAT is pretty simple. your PC creates a packet for google:80 from local:60000, and the router just records that a connection was initiated between those two endpoints. The router does not attempt any additional remapping of ports, and just passes traffic back and forth without processing it at the TCP layer (so its not like you are using port 60000 on the router). if multiple internal systems are using the same destination/port, syn/ack values help it disambiguate what logical circuit the packet is associated with.

as for your question, there isn't a way to know without knowing the details of how the server service implementation operates (some services reply on the listening port, others negotiate a new connection on a different port), and how the network periphery is set up. so this is largely up to however google wants to do it. most HTTP servers i've worked with just continue to use the listening port to respond.

OK. So I looked this up again, and apparently domestic routers tend to use NAPT.
"The vast bulk of Internet traffic uses Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) or User Datagram Protocol (UDP). For these protocols, the port numbers are changed so that the combination of IP address (within the IP header) and port number (within the Transport Layer header) on the returned packet can be unambiguously mapped to the corresponding private network destination. RFC 2663 uses the term network address and port translation (NAPT) for this type of NAT."


Does the Google router just send the message to the google server using port 80, and if so, what happens when the Google server replies?

This kind of NAT is usually stateful and keeps track of connections or "flows". The first packet causes the translation state to be remembered (e.g. so that the router would know which internal address to deliver replies to), and all subsequent packets in both directions re-use the same mapping as long as they're part of the same flow.
For example, on the client side, if the router has decided to translate the source from internal:60000 to external:61000, it'll do so consistently for the entire duration of the connection, and of course will use the same mapping to forward incoming replies back to internal:60000.
The same applies also if the server is behind NAT: the first inbound packet establishes the state (in this case according to a static "port forwarding" rule) and all outbound replies automatically follow the same mapping in reverse.
So if the first inbound packet was to external:80 and got translated to internal:8989, then all outbound replies from internal:8989 (to the same client address:port) will be NATed to appear as if coming from external:80 – the source port won't change because the mapping has already been established.
(That being said: do not assume that the server is behind NAT at all! At the scale of Google they most likely are, but it's also just as common for web servers to have a public IP address all to themselves without any NAT.)

Does the server reply on a different port, which is then translated on the way out, and therefore further replies from my machine are no longer to port 80 and are to whatever the 'public facing' port is?

No. There's only one protocol which does this – TFTP – whereas all other protocols that I've seen will reply from the same port as the original. (It actually means NATs have to specifically recognize TFTP, and sometimes TFTP just doesn't work through NAT.)
(Also, the method you describe was apparently how the ARPANET ICP worked before the invention of TCP/IP but that doesn't really count anymore...)
